# How to repeat value on html form?

Tags: php, html

I am testing a form to see if i can have it pull a php file. Now i am new to coding so there might be an easier way to do it but this is how i am doing it.

Now this is what i did, i create this html code

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input name="folder" type="text" />     
<input type="submit" name="dir" value="" /></form>
```

so when i click on the submit button it takes my url and it makes it look like this.

```
http://localhost/search.php?folder=Dragon+Ball+Z&dir=
```

now the only thing that i am missing is for a way to make the &dir= the same as what i input. so it should look like this.

```
http://localhost/test.php?search.php?folder=Dragon%20Ball%20Z&dir=Dragon%20Ball%20Z
```

Please ignore the %20 that is another thing that i have to fix later but yea how can i make the &dir= part the same as the ?folder= part ?

Thanks and sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate it? You already have the value in `folder`

Comment: In general `dir` GET variable contains the value of the submit button (in your case an empty string). There is no reason to have two GET parameters with one and the same value, just use `folder` value in your `search.php` script (even if you want to assign it to `dir` there).

Comment: Ok thanks i got it work with the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as @Vuldo say in comment why need duplicate that value. But if you want to do so you can do simply by using `JS`

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return duplicate();">
<input name="folder" id="folder" type="text" />     
<input type="submit" name="dir" id="dir" value="" /></form>
<script>
function duplicate(){
    var val = document.getElementById("folder").value;
    document.getElementById("dir").value = val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: is because of the way that i did the PHP it uses the same value 2. but this works thanks so much :)

Comment: Never mind i edit the comment because i dont know how to post code here, well thanks anyway sorry for the bad comment format.